# Column name repeating in query results

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I am giving a select statement in SQL*Plus. It is retreiving the data but the column name is displayed every time after certain number of rows. I want the column name to be displayed only once.

For example:

```
select emp_name from employee.
```

currently gets output:

```
emp_name
========
raman
sunil
rajesh
dilip

emp_name
========
rahul
pramod
ankita
```

I want output like this:

```
emp_name
========
pankaj
ruchi
amar
rakesh
dilip
raju
rahul
```

all under single column heading. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5):

You get this effect because the page size is less than the number of rows returned.  The default is 14.  If you set it to a value greater than the number of rows, no additional headers will be inserted.  You can set the pagesize during a sql*plus session with this command:

```
set pagesize n
```

where n is then number of rows.  So to set it to 200:

```
set pagesize 200
```

Comment: ik_zelf's answer is essentially the same; pages is an abbreviation for pagesize.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what Colin and ik_zelf said:

```
set pages 0
```

or

```
set pagesize 0
```

Sqlplus will suppress all headings, page breaks and titles

Answer (score 1):

Try outputting the result of your query to a file, e.g.:

```
SQL>SPOOL /tmp/mydata.dat   
SQL>select emp_name from employees;
SQL>SPOOL OFF
```

Answer (score 1):

See http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b31189/ch12040.htm#SQPUG095

set pages 50000

Ronald