# How do I join my 3 split output queries in to 1 output table?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I am required to list the number of fixed extras in EVERY DOUBLE and TWIN room type (including those with none). I have typed out the code and got the results that I needed but it is split in to 3 result tables. Each one is 11 rows (the 4th one has only 1 row). How can I combine the 3 to make 1 table?

My code:

```
SELECT r.room_number AS "Room", r.room_type AS "Type", COUNT(f.extra_id) AS "Extra"
FROM a2_room r
LEFT JOIN a2_fixed_extra f
ON (r.room_number = f.room_number)
WHERE r.room_type = 'Twin'
OR r.room_type = 'Double'
GROUP BY r.room_number, r.room_type
ORDER BY r.room_number;
```

My results:

```
Room Type        Extra
---- ------ ----------
005  Twin            1
101  Double          1
102  Double          1
103  Double          1
104  Double          1
106  Twin            1
107  Double          1
108  Double          1
109  Twin            0
110  Twin            0
111  Twin            0

Room Type        Extra
---- ------ ----------
113  Double          1
114  Double          2
115  Twin            0
117  Double          1
118  Double          1
120  Twin            1
201  Double          1
202  Double          1
203  Twin            1
204  Twin            0
207  Twin            0

Room Type        Extra
---- ------ ----------
208  Double          1
209  Double          1
210  Double          1
211  Double          1
217  Double          1
218  Double          2
219  Double          1
220  Twin            0
221  Twin            0
222  Twin            1
223  Double          1

Room Type        Extra
---- ------ ----------
224  Double          1
```

What is needed:

```
-- Room Type       Extras
-- ---- ------ ----------
-- 005  Twin            1
-- 101  Double          1
-- 102  Double          1
-- 103  Double          1
-- 104  Double          1
-- 106  Twin            1
-- 107  Double          1
-- 108  Double          1
-- 109  Twin            0
-- 110  Twin            0
-- 111  Twin            0
-- 113  Double          1
-- 114  Double          2
-- 115  Twin            0
-- 117  Double          1
-- 118  Double          1
-- 120  Twin            1
-- 201  Double          1
-- 202  Double          1
-- 203  Twin            1
-- 204  Twin            0
-- 207  Twin            0
-- 208  Double          1
-- 209  Double          1
-- 210  Double          1
-- 211  Double          1
-- 217  Double          1
-- 218  Double          2
-- 219  Double          1
-- 220  Twin            0
-- 221  Twin            0
-- 222  Twin            1
-- 223  Double          1
-- 224  Double          1
```

Comment: This is only the way the Oracle SQL-Developer is displaying the result. The query returns only one table.

Comment: This is not a problem with your SQL, it's just how SQL Developer formats things by default if you use "Run Script" instead of "Run Statement." I'm sure it's possible to change the format, but I'd suggest just using "Run Statement" instead.

Comment: If you do want to use "Run Script", I think the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073291/column-name-repeating-in-query-results will help you. Run `set pagesize 0` then run your query.

Comment: @Edm, if you do that, output won't have headings any more, so `0` probably isn't the right choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is about the *pagesize* (as commented). Just beware of value you'll be setting it to!

This is what you have now (illustrated on Scott's sample `emp` table):

```
SQL> select empno, ename, job, sal from emp order by ename;

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              SAL
---------- ---------- --------- ----------
      7876 ADAMS      CLERK           1100
      7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN        1600
      7698 BLAKE      MANAGER         2850
      7782 CLARK      MANAGER         2450
      7902 FORD       ANALYST         3000
      7900 JAMES      CLERK            950

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              SAL
---------- ---------- --------- ----------
      7566 JONES      MANAGER         2975
      7839 KING       PRESIDENT       5000
      7654 MARTIN     SALESMAN        1250
      7934 MILLER     CLERK           1300
      7788 SCOTT      ANALYST         3000
      7369 SMITH      CLERK            840

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              SAL
---------- ---------- --------- ----------
      7844 TURNER     SALESMAN        1500
      7521 WARD       SALESMAN        1250

14 rows selected.
```

One of comments says that you should set the pagesize to `0`; you can, and it'll "fix" what's bothering you, but you'll also lose **headings**:

```
SQL> set pagesize 0
SQL> /                                          --> see? No headings
      7876 ADAMS      CLERK           1100        
      7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN        1600
      7698 BLAKE      MANAGER         2850
      7782 CLARK      MANAGER         2450
      7902 FORD       ANALYST         3000
      7900 JAMES      CLERK            950
      7566 JONES      MANAGER         2975
      7839 KING       PRESIDENT       5000
      7654 MARTIN     SALESMAN        1250
      7934 MILLER     CLERK           1300
      7788 SCOTT      ANALYST         3000
      7369 SMITH      CLERK            840
      7844 TURNER     SALESMAN        1500
      7521 WARD       SALESMAN        1250

14 rows selected.
```

Therefore, set it to value which suits your needs. For number of rows you expect, 1000 might be reasonably high enough:

```
SQL> set pagesize 1000
SQL> /

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              SAL      --> heading is here,
---------- ---------- --------- ----------      --> result isn't split
      7876 ADAMS      CLERK           1100      --> into several groups
      7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN        1600      --> any more
      7698 BLAKE      MANAGER         2850
      7782 CLARK      MANAGER         2450
      7902 FORD       ANALYST         3000
      7900 JAMES      CLERK            950
      7566 JONES      MANAGER         2975
      7839 KING       PRESIDENT       5000
      7654 MARTIN     SALESMAN        1250
      7934 MILLER     CLERK           1300
      7788 SCOTT      ANALYST         3000
      7369 SMITH      CLERK            840
      7844 TURNER     SALESMAN        1500
      7521 WARD       SALESMAN        1250

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```